# Deleting comments from a file, using Regex

Tags: regex, f#

I want to write a program that deletes all the comments (starting with "//" until the end of the line) from a file.

I want to do it using regular expressions.

I tried this:

```
    let mutable text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\a.txt")
    let regexComment = new Regex("//.*\\r\\n$") 
    text <- regexComment.Replace(text, "")
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\a.txt",text)
```

But it doesn't work...

Can you please explain to me why, and give me some suggestion to something that does work (preferable using regex..) ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know the constraints you're dealing with but I cannot imagine a situation where using a RegEx is a requirement. In your case, using a .StartsWith to test each string would be simpler and probably much safer. It'd also be lots easier for the people who come after you to maintain.  As I say, I don't know your constraints but I think using a RegEx here is probably adding needless complexity.

Comment: In addition to Onorio's point, a regex-based approach is going to break any code that includes the characters `//` when those characters do not represent a code comment. For example, inside a literal string such as a URL.

Comment: @JoelMueller, or even his code here ;)

Comment: Thank you all, i made sure that it won't split any kind of strings in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let regexComment = new Regex(@"//.*$",RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: I hope your code doesn't include any literal strings that happen to have a url in them. Using this regex to strip comments would make a hash of code like this: `let request = WebRequest.Create("http://foo.com")`

Comment: @JoelMueller - ( as already mentioned) you should say to cookya.

Comment: You will need to check whether it contains a string literal must be handled strictly.

Comment: I was leaving a warning on the accepted answer for anyone who might stumble across this from a search - I wasn't criticizing you personally.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than loading the whole file into memory and running a regex on it, a faster approach that will handle any size file without memory issues might look like this:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

// regex: beginning of line, followed by optional whitespace, 
// followed by comment chars.
let reComment = Regex(@"^\s*//", RegexOptions.Compiled)

let stripComments infile outfile =
    File.ReadLines infile
    |> Seq.filter (reComment.IsMatch >> not)
    |> fun lines -> File.WriteAllLines(outfile, lines)


stripComments "input.txt" "output.txt"
```

The output file must be different from the input file, because we're writing to the output while we're still reading from the input. We use the regex to identify comment lines (with optional leading whitespace), and `Seq.filter` to make sure the comment lines don't get sent to the output file.

Because we never hold the entire input or output file in memory, this function will work on any size file, and it's likely faster than the "read entire file, regex everything, write entire file" approach.

**Danger Ahead**

This code will not strip out comments that appear after some code on the same line. However, a regular expression is not the right tool for that job, unless someone can come up with a regular expression that can tell the following two lines of code apart and avoid breaking the first one when you strip everything that matches the regex from the file:

```
let request = WebRequest.Create("http://foo.com")
let request = WebRequest.Create(inputUrl) // this used to be hard-coded
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. It should have been:

```
let regexComment = new Regex("//.*\\r\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex string seems to be wrong.  `"\\/\\/.*\\r\\n"` worked for me.